# Not understanding mongoose schema array syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the below syntax in a mongoose schema.

```
tokens:[{
        token:{
            type: 'String',
            required: true
        }
    }]
```

Normally when I want to add objects to arrays I would just push the object. That includes if I want to push an object with an internal object to said array like the example below.

```
let obj =[]
obj.push({name: 'dirk', age: 24})
obj.push({name: 'chris', age:29, clothes: {shirt: 'black', pants: 'jeans'}, height: '6ft'})
```

So im confused in mongoose as to why I need this syntax `[{}]` to use an array?

Comment: Just a heads up I got that syntax from the document example in mongoose - var Empty4 = new Schema({ any: [{}] });

Comment: So is your question why you would have `any: [{}]` or why you can't use `obj = []` and then just start pushing?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt the latter. Why can i use obj = [ ] and start pushing

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll try to explain this as best I can.  In basic JavaScript, an array is just a bucket of "stuff" for lack of better words.  What that means is, you could have something like this:

```
let myList = []
myList.push({name: "John Doe", age: 20})
myList.push({car: {make: "Honda", model: "Accord"}})
myList.push({menu_items: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]})
```

And JavaScript won't really care right?  As far as it's concerned, you haven't done anything wrong because you technically did the correct thing, put some object into a list that can hold whatever you want.

Mongoose, which is an ORM (check out the term if you haven't heard of it before), requires things be a little more strict.  Remember that Mongoose is trying to map documents from the Mongo database to this "Object" that should be standard and readable from any point in the code the same what.  So in the example in your question listed above:

```
tokens:[{
    token:{
        type: 'String',
        required: true
    }
}]
```

you are saying to Mongoose that it should expect `tokens` to contain a list of `token` objects that have a certain design to them.  Now, when you want to add more `token` objects to the `tokens` list, you can do something like this:

```
token = { 
    // YOUR CORRECT TOKEN DATA
}

tokens.push(token);
```

If you tried to do something like this instead:

```
token = { 
    // RANDOM WRONG DATA
}

tokens.push(token);
```

Mongoose wouldn't take kindly to it because you are violating the constraints you told Mongoose to keep in affect.  If you start throwing `any: [{}]` into the mix, you are telling Mongoose that any old object will do for that list.  This is, in my opinion, very dangerous to do because if you have two types of objects in your list:

```
var schema1 = new Schema({
   name:    String,
   age:  { type: Number, min: 18, max: 65 },
   living:  Boolean
})

var schema2 = new Schema({
   name:    String,
   age:  { type: Number, min: 18, max: 65 },
   breed:  Boolean
})
```

and you were working with a list that combined these two objects, if you tried to grab say `breed` from the `schema1` type object, you would either get an error or an odd value that could break your code.  So Mongoose strictly types the objects you are pushing to a list, unless you use something like `Mixed` or `any`.  Here's a link to the documentation that may help explain a bit as well

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays

If this doesn't make sense or I explained it poorly or answered the wrong question please comment and I'll fix it to explain as best I can.

Happy coding :-)